# R: Speeding up Code, multicore

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multicore

I have a problem with the Performance of my R Code.
My Code is very slow. I have to loop over a vector of 3000 elements. On every loop I call many functions.
I tried first with parallelization, but it doesn’t work. In every step I need the results previous steps.
Now I have an idea: I would divide the vector in 3 pieces of 1000 elements. And make the calculation of each piece by itself. On the first element of piece 1 and 2, I will have a problem, but I can handle it.
I would like to calculate each of the 3 pieces by a separate CPU-Core.
Actually I could make 3 .R-Files and start 3 R-Sessions (=3 Cores) and calculate it.
But I would like to do it in one file. I would like to define, that my first loop is going to be calculated by Core 1, and the other ones by the other Cores.

Is it possible? 
Thank you.

This is an simple Example. It describes my problem.

```
#Situation now  
vec3000 <- rnorm(3000)
result3000 <- rep(NA, length(vec3000))
for (i in 1 : 3000){
    if (i == 1){
        result3000[i] <- vec3000[i]
    }else{
        result3000[i] <- result3000[i - 1] + vec3000[i]
    }
}

#New Situation
vec1000_1 <- vec3000[1:1000]
vec1000_2 <- vec3000[1001:2000]
vec1000_3 <- vec3000[2001:3000]
result1000_1 <- rep(NA, 1000)
result1000_2 <- rep(NA, 1000)
result1000_3 <- rep(NA, 1000)

#Calculated by Core 1
for (i in 1 : 1000){
    if (i == 1){
        result1000_1[i] <- vec1000_1[i]
    }else{
        result1000_1[i] <- result1000_1[i - 1] + vec1000_1[i]
    }
}

#Calculated by Core 2
for (i in 1 : 1000){
    if (i == 1){
        result1000_2[i] <- vec1000_2[i]
    }else{
        result1000_2[i] <- result1000_2[i - 1] + vec1000_2[i]
    }
}   

#Calculated by Core 3
for (i in 1 : 1000){
    if (i == 1){
        result1000_3[i] <- vec1000_3[i]
    }else{
        result1000_3[i] <- result1000_3[i - 1] + vec1000_3[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, so others can help more easily. You will get better/quicker answers, better suited to your particular problem.

Comment: Yes it's possible: see the `parallels` package for one example. Whether this is the best way to reduce your process time is unknowable, as you've failed to post either your functions or your desired output.  It's likely there's a much better way to calculate the results you desire.

Comment: `result1000_1 = cumsum(vec1000_1)` will be fast, no need to waste time parallelizing inefficient code.

Comment: Have you even tried running this in parallel?

Comment: I know i can use here cumsum. But this is an Example. My Problem is more complicated. I didn’t try exactly this example in parallel. But my Example generates an Error. : 
**Error in { : task 1 failed - "Objekt of Type 'S4'….**

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the foreach package that operates on vector chunks in parallel:

```
library(doParallel)
library(itertools)
nworkers <- 3
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(nworkers)
registerDoParallel(cl)
vec3000 <- rnorm(3000) # dummy input

# This computes "resvecs" which is a list of "nworkers" vectors
resvecs <- foreach(vec=isplitVector(vec3000, chunks=nworkers)) %dopar% {
    result <- double(length=length(vec))
    for (i in seq_along(result)) {
        if (i == 1) {
            result[i] <- vec[i]
        } else {
            result[i] <- result[i - 1] + vec[i]
        }
    }
    result
}
```

This uses the "isplitVector" function from the itertools package to split "vec3000" into three chunks to make use of three cores. You can change the value of "nworkers" to control the number of cores that are used.

Note that I used the doParallel backend so the example would work on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.

Comment: Thanks. Your example ist perfect.